# Haskell : Recursive definition of a tuple

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda-calculus

In it I'm trying to create a Krivine Abstract Machine. One of the data types I need to build is an environment. An Environment is built as such:

We have x, a "Var" (This is just a synonym for string)
We have N, a "Term" (This is a Lambda term)

So the definition of an environment E is:

E = (x, N, E) · E.

So an environment is a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a Var (String), A Term and a list of environments (which may be empty).

I'm defining "Env" like so:

```
data Env = Env (Var, Term, [Env])
```

To me, this looks as if it should work. However, when I try to utilise Env, I get:

```
*Main> ("y", Lambda "z" (Variable "z"), []) :: Env

<interactive>:166:1: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `Env'
              with actual type `([Char], Term, [a0])'
* In the expression: ("y", Lambda "z" (Variable "z"), []) :: Env
  In an equation for `it':
      it = ("y", Lambda "z" (Variable "z"), []) :: Env
```

"y" is certainly [Char]

Lambda "z" (Variable "z") is definitely of type Term

And an empty list is definitely a list!

I have a feeling that the problem may be occurring with the empty list, but it's absolutely essential that an empty list can be present within an environment (this is the base case).

I've now been trying to get this working for a few hours with no luck at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```hs
data Env = Env (Var, Term, [Env])
```

Here you define the type `Env` and the data constructor `Env`. They have the same name, but the data constructor `Env` is a value with type:

```
ghci> :t Env
Env :: (Var, Term, [Env]) -> Env
```

The constructor defines a mapping from tuples to `Env` values. It can also be used in pattern matching to map from `Env` values to tuples:

```
ghci> :t \(Env t) -> t
\(Env t) -> t :: Env -> (Var, Term, [Env])
```

The trick is that though values of type `Env` are isomorphic to tuples `(Var, Term, [Env])`, they have a different type; `Env`. This is *nominitive* typing, rather that *structural* typing. It very useful when we want to have values that have the same structure under the hood, but are distinct in the type system, e.g.

```hs
data SecondsAfterMidnight = SecondsAfterMidnight Int
data PenniesPerHour = PenniesPerHour Int
```

This prevents us from doing something like `fiveCentsPerHour + oneFifteenAM`.

That said, sometimes you just want a more convenient name for a complicated type and you don't want it to be distinct from the complicated type.  Haskell has *type aliases* to handle this case. For example, `String` is a type alias for `[Char]` (a list of char); they're two names for the same type.

If it weren't recursive and you didn't want to bother with a constructor, you could use a type alias by using the `type` keyword:

```
type Env = (Var, Term, [SomethingElse])
```

But you can't use type aliases to define recursive types as they would then infinitely expand at compile time.

Another way you could go is to ditch the tuple and embrace your `Env` constructor:

```
data Env = Env Var Term [Env]
```

Now the `Env` constructor takes three parameters, rather than a tuple.

```
ghci> :t Env
Env :: Var -> Term -> [Env] -> Env
```

You can also use record syntax to get getters for the various fields:

```
data Env = Env { var :: Var, term :: Term, env :: [Env] }
```

These can be pretty handy:

```
ghci> :t var
var :: Env -> Var
ghci> :t term
term :: Env -> Term
ghci> :t env
env :: Env -> [Env]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Using data and ditching the tuple certainly works, but it would simplify things if it were in the form of a tuple. `type Env = (Var, Term, [Env])` looked promising, but when I try to use it I get `Cycle in type synonym declarations`, and it refuses to compile. I saw a similar definition for a vertex in another post, but the compiler doesn't seem to like it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot it was recursive. You can't have recursive aliases because that would lead to infinite types `(Var, Term [(Var, Term, [(Var, Term, [...`.

It's recursive, so you'll need to have a `data` declaration and a constructor.

Comment: I see, slightly more painful but I'm sure I can push through :) Thank you!

Comment: @Jimmy I don't know exactly what pain points you're finding, but there are a number of common ways to alleviate boilerplate, such as deriving Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, which very often can make your life easier.